# Verify this finite product $\prod_{r=1}^{2^k}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{r}{2^k}\right)^{(-1)^r}$

Tags: gamma-function, products

How can we show that,

$$\prod_{r=1}^{2^k}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{r}{2^k}\right)^{(-1)^r}=\frac{(2^k-2)!!}{(2^k-1)!!}\cdot \frac{2^k}{\sqrt{2^{k-1}\pi}}$$

Where $\Gamma(n)$; [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle f(n):=\prod\limits_{r=1}^n\Gamma\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)\hspace{3cm}$ See [GammaMultiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem).

$\displaystyle \prod\limits_{r=1}^{2^k}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{r}{2^k}\right)^{(-1)^r}=\frac{f(2^{k-1})^2}{f(2^k)}$

The rest is routine.